# Call an instance variable when its name is same with the argument variable

Tags: java, static, naming-conventions

I have this code:

```
class Foo {
 int x = 12;

public static void go(final int x) {

    System.out.println(x);

}
}
```

The argument final x and the instance x have the same name. How would I refer to the instance variable x = 12 if I want to use it in the go() method considering its name is the same with the argument variable?

Answer (score 6):

You need to make it static in order to use it within static method:

```
static int x = 12;
```

Then you can get a reference to it via the class name:

```
public static void go(final int x)
{
    System.out.println(Foo.x);
}
```

---

Or alternatively, create an instance and use it locally:

```
int x = 12;

public static void go(final int x)
{
    Foo f = new Foo();
    System.out.println(f.x);
}
```

---

Or use instance method, and refer to the instance `x` with the keyword `this`:

```
int x = 12;

public void go(final int x)
{
    System.out.println(this.x);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`this.x` points to the instance variable.

In order to refer to an *instance* variable, you have to be in a real instance: your method should not be `static` then.

Comment: you were the first to notice the method is static. But your answer is still wrong. It's not possible to use `this` in a `static` method.

Comment: I bet my house that the method is marked as `static` by the OP, just because it is called from `main()`, and not by real need.

Comment: That's possible, and your answer is right. But it's not clear at first read, maybe you should add that he should remove `static` from his method signature to make `this.x` work.